# For checking non-blank cell(s), what is the difference between "ISBLANK(cell)=FALSE" and just the "cell" itself for IF statements, for Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

As I work with my Excel document, I notice the following seems to give the same output if I want to check if a cell or cells is non-empty.

Using ISBLANK()

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2)=FALSE,1,0)
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),0,1)
```

Using just the cell itself, B2

```
=IF(B2,1,0)
```

Both output 1 if the cell is not empty and 0 if it is empty it seems like. I think the cell itself would output the cell itself so if it's a number, it should be true, and is it's blank, it's false, while the ISBLANK() returns boolean values.

I believe if they are used in IF statements, then they are equivalent? I'm also not sure if one uses more computational power.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that there is a difference, and the main difference is that if the value of the cell is ***"0"***.

Then the ISBLANK() function will output TRUE, but the B2 cell function would just output 0, which would be equivalent to FALSE in an IF() statement.

It seems the cell function itself would be good for summing up/averaging numbers where you don't want to count outliers where there is a "0" in the function, so it seems equivalent to this for IF statements:

```
IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2)=FALSE,B2<>0),1,0)
```

Let me know if there is a mistake